# Ошибка при создании файла/папки bitrix

Tags: веб-программирование, файлы, битрикс, cms

Недавно была ошибка с `.htaccess` и на сайте висела ошибка `500`, потом кто-то исправил, но теперь в CMS'ке при создании папки или файла выскакивает ошибка - "Не удалось создать папку "Название""

Я заметил, что если создать папку в "/"(корень), - единственное место, где хоть что-то создается -, то в значении "Права на доступ сервера" написано `755 apache apache`, а во всех других папках это значение другое - `755 vostorg vostorg` (`vostorg` - название сайта).

**Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.**

Часть файла `dbconn.php`:

```
...
define("BX_FILE_PERMISSIONS", 0644);
define("BX_DIR_PERMISSIONS", 0755);
@umask(~BX_DIR_PERMISSIONS);
@ini_set("memory_limit", "512M");
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта проблема связана с правами на файл в самой файловой системе, в папке где лежит проект попробуйте в консоли выполнить следующее:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; 
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

скорее всего файлы заливались по `ftp` и т.п.

Comment: a как открыть командную строку в определенной папке? Файл командной строки ведь лежит в /bitrix/admin/php_command_line.php

Comment: надо подключиться по ssh к серверу, и в консоли сервера выполнить эти команды. `/bitrix/admin/php_command_line.php` - это php консоль

Comment: Тут проблемка, сервер чисто на FTP, есть идеи как можно решить проблему?